# Wordpress plugins functionality working fine on desktop But not working properly on mobile. Why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, shortcode

**I have created a Wordpress Accent(text-to-speech) plugins/shortcode for our wordpress site (https//speaktoday.com).** **It's functionality working fine on desktop but whenever I open it mobile it showing a pop-up "speaktoday.com  wants to use speech (deny and allow)". Also its functionality (text-to-speech) is not working in mobile.**
And i don't want to show that pop-up message while open my website on mobile and also that plugin's functionality should work fine on mobile device too.
Please give me the proper solution for that.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
/** Plugin Name: SpeakToday_Accent
    Description: This plugin is used to select preferred accent
    Author: Amit  Singh
    Version: 1.0
    link : https://speaktoday.com

*/
add_shortcode( 'TTSdefault', 'voice_counter' );
function voice_counter($att,$content){
    $att = shortcode_atts(array('lang' => ''),$att);
    $languageVal = $att['lang'];
    //echo "<h2>".$languageVal."</h2>";

?>

<script src="https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
<script src="//code.responsivevoice.org/1.5.6/responsivevoice.js"></script>

<script>
setTimeout(responsiveVoice.speak("",$('#voiceselection').val()),15000);
</script>
<script>



function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();

    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") { 
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}
$(document).ready(function (){ 
   $(document).mouseup(function (e){ 
      setTimeout(function() { 
         responsiveVoice.cancel(); 
         var text = $('#voiceselection').val();
          responsiveVoice.speak(getSelectionText(), text ); 

      }, 1);
   });
});
</script>
<div class = "speaktoday_accent" style="background:white;width:155px; position: relative !important;transform: none !important; display: inline-block;">
 <select id="voiceselection" style="width:155;line-height:2;">
  <option value="UK English Female">UK English Female</option>
    <option value="US English Female">US English Female</option>
    <option value="Hindi Female">Hindi Female</option>
    <option value="UK English Male">UK English Male</option>
    <option value="US English Male">US English Male</option>
     </select>
</div>

<script>
    var spge = <?php echo json_encode($languageVal); ?>;
    //alert(spge);
         $("#voiceselection").on('change', function () {
             window.localStorage.setItem("voiceselection", this.value);
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var n = sessionStorage.getItem('on_load_counter');
             if (n === null) {
             n = 0;
             }
              n++;
            sessionStorage.setItem("on_load_counter", n);

            if(n>1){
                 $("#voiceselection").val(window.localStorage.getItem("voiceselection"));
                $('select option[value="voiceselection"]').attr("selected",true);
            }
            else{

                //alert(spge);
            // $("#voiceselection").val(window.localStorage.getItem("voiceselection"));

            //alert(spge);
            $("#voiceselection").val(spge).change();
                //$('select option[value="UK English Female"]').attr("selected",true);
            }

            //alert(n);
        });
</script>


<?php

}
```

please help me solve these issues.
 You can visit https://speaktoday.com  to see that plugins . When you scroll down you'll see a language selection dropdown.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way around the prompt to allow permissions to use your device hardware. Imagine any site could just listen to the microphone without consent. You most likely have allowed permission on desktop (and has remembered it).

Also a mobile device does not have a `mouseup` event. Try using the `blur` event, or have a cancelling timeout with `change`.

Comment: why 'Unfortunately'?

Comment: It is unfortunate for Amit?

Comment: ))) I mean, logically, nobody would like to have the big hole in his device, like use device hardware from some website